# Is it possible to show AWS CloudWatch metrics graphs on your own dashboard webpage?

Tags: amazon-aws, metrics

Is it possible to show AWS CloudWatch metrics graphs on your own dashboard webpage?

It would save the hassle of logging into the AWS console when something weird is going on.

Comment: you should take a look at the cloud watch api https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudwatch/

Comment: What languages do you have experience in?

Comment: Since I posted this question it has become a lot easier - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-dashboard-sharing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post describes the exact steps (official AWS documentation) to do this:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-an-amazon-cloudwatch-dashboard-outside-of-the-aws-management-console/

You'll need to use CloudWatch snapshot graphs to achieve the same.

Comment: I like to think that this post of mine is what inspired Amazon to make this possible.

Answer (score 4):

As a basic start, try checking out Google app engine for hosting this project.

Check out the basics of [Boto](https://boto.readthedocs.org/). Then look at using Boto to [access cloudwatch data](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html). Build a client that outputs the data you want to the terminal when a function is called.

Take the basic [appengine tutorial](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine). Then, look up the basics of [webapp2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingwebapp) and the [Jinja templating enjine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). Make basic pages.

Then, tie this in with your python program. Start the webapp2 file with `import [name of your couldwatch python file in the same folder]`. Then, in the `get` handler in your webapp2 program, send `[name imported].[function-name]()` to your Jinja template to make the page.

This should take a few hours to complete.

**Important: There is a reason that Amazon keeps this data behind a login page. Think deeply about the security implications of what you are doing.**

I highly recommend password-protecting the webpage that will display the data. If you will already be signed into your Google account, the super-simple way is to use [google app engine's built in login mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status) to require administrator login.

Comment: That looks like a fun project.  Thanks.  Of course my dashboard and admin pages are protected with HTTPS and digest authentication.

Comment: @paradroid Google app engine will make very secure login even easier, I highly recommend it

Comment: Sure, I'll check it out.  Cheers.

Comment: This project appears to do a lot of this for you https://github.com/mbabineau/cloudviz